# C# collection combine entries

Tags: c#

```
    public class Contact
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Fax { get; set; }
        public string Email {get; set; }
    }
```

if I have a list of contacts that looks like the following:

```
List<Contact> contactList = 
╔═════╦══════╦═════════════╗
║Name ║ Fax  ║ Email       ║
╠═════╬══════╬═════════════╣
║  a  ║ 1    ║             ║
║  b  ║      ║ b@email.com ║
║  c  ║ 3    ║ c@email.com ║
║  a  ║      ║ a@email.com ║           
║  b  ║ 2    ║             ║
╚═════╩══════╩═════════════╝
```

How can I combine the entries with the same Name and produce this result ?

```
╔═════╦══════╦═════════════╗
║Name ║ Fax  ║ Email       ║
╠═════╬══════╬═════════════╣
║  a  ║ 1    ║ a@email.com ║
║  b  ║ 2    ║ b@email.com ║
║  c  ║ 3    ║ c@email.com ║
╚═════╩══════╩═════════════╝
```

This is what I tried so far:

```
var result = contactList.Select(contact => contact.Name)
                             .Distinct()
                             .Select(name => contactList.First(contact => contact.Name == name))
                             .ToList();


 foreach (var contact in contactList)
            {
                var c = result.First(r => r.Name == contact.Name);
                c.Name = string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(contact.Name) ? c.Name : contact.Name;
                c.Fax = string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(contact.Fax ? c.Fax : contact.Fax;
                c.Email = string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(contact.Email) ? c.Email : contact.Email;
            }
```

Is there a more efficient way ?

Comment: What's your duplicate definition? What's your desired result?

Comment: Are you asking how to combine like items? What constitutes a "duplicate" because by my definition there are no duplicates.

Comment: It might be more efficient to add extra information as you build the `List<Contact>`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you need to do a `GroupBy` and then I'm assuming those values are null values so you just want to get the first non-null value.

```
var results = (from contact in constactList
               group contact by contact.Name into contacts
               select new Contact
               {
                   Name = contacts.Key,
                   Fax = contacts.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Fax != null)?.Fax,
                   Email = contacts.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Email != null)?.Email 
               }).ToList();
```

Or in method syntax

```
var results = constactList.GroupBy(contact => contact.Name)
    .Select(contacts => new Contact
    {
        Name = contacts.Key,
        Fax = contacts.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Fax != null)?.Fax,
        Email = contacts.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Email != null)?.Email 
    }).ToList();
```

Or if they are blank strings you could also do

```
Fax = contacts.FirstOrDefault(c => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(c.Fax))?.Fax
```

And if you don't have C# 6 then the following

```
Fax = contacts.Where(c => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(c.Fax)).Select(c => c.Fax).FirstOrDefault()
```

Comment: Thank you. your solution is very clear and thorough.

Answer (score 1):

You may use a Dictionary. Iterate through the list to get missing information and filter duplicates:

```
var dict = new Dictionary<string, Contact>();
foreach (var contact in contactList)
{
    Contact existingContact;
    if (dict.TryGetValue(contact.Name, out existingContact))
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(existingContact.Fax))
            existingContact.Fax = contact.Fax;
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(existingContact.Email))
            existingContact.Email = contact.Email;
    }
    else
    {
        dict.Add(contact.Name, contact);
    }
}
var list = dict.Values.ToList();
```

Complexity of this method is O(n). Also, it requires O(n) additional memory.

Answer (score 0):

You should think that there might be entries with no email or fax.

```
var contactList = new List<Contact> {
    new Contact { Name="a", Fax = "1", Email=""},
    new Contact { Name="b", Fax = "", Email="b@email.com"},
    new Contact { Name="c", Fax = "3", Email="c@email.com"},
    new Contact { Name="a", Fax = "", Email="a@email.com"},
    new Contact { Name="b", Fax = "2", Email=""},

};

var result = (from c in contactList
                .Where(contact => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(contact.Name))
                .Select(c => c.Name)
                .Distinct()
             let fax = contactList.FirstOrDefault(contact => contact.Name == c &&
                     !string.IsNullOrEmpty(contact.Fax))
             let email = contactList.FirstOrDefault(contact => contact.Name == c &&
                     !string.IsNullOrEmpty(contact.Email))
             select new Contact {
                 Name = c,
                 Fax = fax == null ? "" : fax.Fax,
                 Email = email == null ? "" : email.Email
             })
             .ToList();
```